# No chuncks uploaded using plupload and flash

Tags: flash, plupload, chunked

I'm using plupload 2.1.2 and chunked upload. Runtime is set to flash for testing, chunk-size is 5242880.

When i start uploading, i don't get any chunk uploading calls but after a short time, i get a FileUploaded callback.

The test-file I'm using is 160mb.

When i set runtime to html5 everything is working fine.

I tested using firefox 34.0.

The object is initialized like this:

```
var settings = {
  runtimes : 'flash',
  browse_button : "id_of_the_dom_element",
  container: document.body,
  url : '/relative/url',
  flash_swf_url : 'assets/flash/Moxie.swf',
  multi_selection: false,
  chunk_size : '5242880'
};

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(settings);

uploader.init();
```

-e-
The problem occurs also when i disable chunking. I get a FileUploaded callback before the file gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from github:

Chunking is disabled in Flash runtime by default, since it doesn't do what it is meant to in Flash. Check: [When to use chunking and when not?.](http://plupload.com/docs/Frequently-Asked-Questions#when-to-use-chunking-and-when-not)

If you want to enable chunking anyway, set: required_features to true.

Source: https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1188